# 2-Way Table Look Up in Excel Using VLOOKUP and MATCH Returning Error

Tags: excel

I'm working an a cell formula that will perform a 2 dimensional look-up on table.

My the formula is as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A97,A4:L10,MATCH(B96,A4:L4,0),FALSE)
```

However, it is returning a #N/A error.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with formatting, but I can't say for sure.  In any case, the column headers of my table array are formatted as numbers (years), the row labels are formatted as text, and the actual data in the array is a custom format with the data pulled from other sheets in the workbook.

Is it something with formatting, or is that not a factor?  If not, is there something wrong with the formula itself?

Thanks.

-Sean

Comment: So B96 contains a specific year? Try testing the match part on its own - does `=MATCH(B96,A4:L4,0)` give you #N/A? - if B96 is a date then change B96 in formula to YEAR(B96)

Comment: VLOOKUP and MATCH is a bit of a strange combination - did you mean to use INDEX and MATCH?

Comment: It's a viable approach for a two dimensional lookup, although INDEX/MATCH/MATCH is more common.....the MATCH determines the column_index for the VLOOKUP, i.e. the column from which the result is returned

Comment: @barryhoudini B96 does contain a year, but it's not formatted as a date.  The MATCH function does not work on its own.  I tried changing B96 to YEAR(B96) as you suggested, but that doesn't solve the issue either.  Could it be because the content in the lookup table (A4:L4) is being pulled from another worksheet?

Comment: @DaveSexton I tried using the INDEX and MATCH functions together in the following format:

`=INDEX(A1:E14, MATCH(H2,A1:A14,0), MATCH(H3,A1:E1,0))`

But that wasn't working either.

Comment: Yes - the problem isn't with the method - if A4:L4 is text this might work `=VLOOKUP(A97,A4:L10,MATCH(B96&"",A4:L4,0),FALSE)` - that converts B96 to a text value within the MATCH function

Comment: @barryhoudini Your suggestion solved the issue.  Also, I switched back the INDEX/MATCH/MATCH format as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @barryhoudini and @DaveSexton for the solution... I'm just documenting it officially.

First off, the error I was receiving was due to the formatting of the source cell.  So, per Barry's suggestion, I concatenated a "" to the end of my cell reference, which formatted the source cell as text, allowing the function to work.  New code:

```
=VLOOKUP(A97,A4:L10,MATCH(B96&"",A4:L4,0),FALSE)
```

Second, per Dave's suggestion, I abandoned the VLOOKUP/MATCH approach in favor of the INDEX/MATCH/MATCH approach.  E.G:

```
=INDEX(A1:E14, MATCH(H2,A1:A14,0), MATCH(H3,A1:E1,0))
```

Thanks both for your help.